# Disable truncation of hostnames in netstat's output

Tags: networking

By default, the `netstat` command truncates hostnames in it's output. 
How can this truncation of hostnames be disabled in the output of the netstat command?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On older versions of OSX and Ubuntu 10.04/16.04, use the -W flag:

`netstat -W`

On older versions of Linux and OSX 10.13.3, use the -T flag:

`netstat -T`

On Windows 7/8, use the -f flag:

`netstat -f`

Comment: You might want to specify your operating system. `netstat` does not have a `-W` option on Windows 7 (or apparently on Linux) ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Updated my answer. Added Linux-specific information. Can you test on Windows 7 if the `-T` flag is accepted? I don't have access to a Windows 7 environment.

Comment: @BrandonGalbraith: Win 7's netstat accepts `-T`, but interprets it as `-t`: _Displays the current connection offload state._ `netstat -W` isn't accepted, i.e. it shows the help. See http://www.computerhope.com/netstat.htm

Comment: @mpy I believe the `-f` flag works on Windows 7. I'll test later today on a VM.

Comment: @BrandonGalbraith: Oh yes, looks good!

Comment: @mpy Excellent! Thanks for confirming! I've updated my answer as well!

Comment: Where does that -T flag for Linux come from? On Ubuntu the correct flag is -W (at least in 10.04 and 16.04)

Comment: @Rennex I believe that was on CentOS. I should've noted the specific distro, sorry about that! I'll edit my answer to include you observation.